# massemail with attachment - tmp folder

Tags: file-permissions, tmp

I have a small mailing php script and I would like to extend it with attachment function (we have a DB for our staff to get contact with them).
As far as I understand I need a /tmp folder to be able to upload the attached file - but I need a write permission which would make my site weaker.

Questions:

- How can I be sure that only the user uploads the given fileformat (without SSL)?
- Is there any way to make sure noone else would execute a file or upload anything that is malicious?
- do I need to delete the file after upload or it will be deleted - generally?

I work on a shared host...

Any help would be appreciated.

Andras

ps code is in PHP mail function swift mailer. - apologise for my English and the dummy question:)

Comment: What is your question? Upload, use, delete. Where is the security issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Check it. `file` may be you (first) friend.
- Authentication is the key. How should someone execute a file when it hasn't got the execution bit set? And not the file mode to even see the file?
- Depends on how you implement the upload. But what would be so hard to do a `delete(file)` anyway?